# Can I set TypeName in the constructor of new SqlParameter when setting params for a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using the following code to set up parameters for a call to a stored procedure:

```
        List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", adminTest.Title));
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Text", adminTest.Text));

        var questionsList = new SqlParameter("@Questions", questions);
        questionsList.TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList";
        parameterList.Add(questionsList);
```

The code snippet works but what I would like to know is if anyone found a way to set the `TypeName` in the new SqlParameter constructor? I tried looking at the documentation but the only thing I can find is adding the typename afterwards.

Comment: `QuestionList` is your table type??

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with initializers.  The example below specifies strongly-typed parameters and max length of variable values, which is a good practice from a SQL performance perspective.

```
    List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Size = 30, Value = adminTest.Title},
            new SqlParameter("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Size = 30, Value = adminTest.Text},
            new SqlParameter("@Questions", SqlDbType.Structured) {TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList", Value = questions}
        };
```

Comment: +1 as this does work and definitely good to mention explicit setting of `Size` (though that can also be set in the constructor and does not require using an initializer), but it should still be noted that if `CommandType` is set to `StoredProcedure` then the `TypeName` property is not required or needed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

Create datatable in C#

```
 DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("QuestionList");
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
    myDataTable.Rows.Add("Title", "Text1");
    myDataTable.Rows.Add("Text", "Text2");
```

Create sql parameter

```
  string conStr = "Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
  using (con)
        {
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertQuestionList", con);
            SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                "@QuestionList", myDataTable);
            insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.QuestionList";
            tvpParam.Value = myDataTable;
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        con.Close();
```

Create table type

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.QuestionList AS TABLE
    ( Title varchar(50), TEXT nvarchar(50) )
```

PRODCEDURE to insert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  InsertQuestionList
   @QuestionList QuestionList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 --insert into Your table
 select * from @QuestionList
END
GO
```

Comment: -1 This does not work, at least not in any way that my testing shows. If `CommandType` is set to `StoredProcedure` then the `TypeName` property is not required so you don't see that the name of the `DataTable` is not used at all. If `CommandType` is set to `Text` then the `TypeName` property is required and you do see that the name of the `DataTable` is not used, no matter what it is set to. Besides, if it were to be used, it would at least need to be "dbo.QuestionList", but even fixing that does not help.

Comment: @srutzky updated and tested on my pc now working fine

Comment: Thanks for updating and verifying. The only issue left is that the question is specific to _not_ specifying the `TypeName` property as an additional step. Also, while your code works, you could remove the line that sets `TypeName` and it would still work as the `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure`. But that shows that it isn't looking at the name of the `DataTable`.